# What goes in the indices parameter of glDrawElementsInstanced() using JOGL

Tags: opengl, jogl

I am having trouble understanding what to use as the "indices" parameter when calling glDrawElementsInstanced() in JOGL.

From looking over some C++ tutorials, it seems that you can just pass in 0 for indices as long as you want to start rendering your vertices from the beginning of the index buffer. JOGL requires that the indices parameter be a Buffer object. I tried creating an IntBuffer with one element, 0, inside it but that didn't work.

When I use this to draw my vertices, I see things drawn on the screen:

```
gl.glDrawElements(GL.GL_TRIANGLES, 10, GL.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0)
```

But when I use this instead, the screen is black:

```
gl.glDrawElementsInstanced(
    GL.GL_TRIANGLES, 10, GL.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, IntBuffer.wrap(Array(0)), 1
)
```

When I use this, I get a type mismatch error:

```
gl.glDrawElementsInstanced(
    GL.GL_TRIANGLES, 10, GL.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, 1
)
```

I am using OpenGL 4 and Scala. I have also set my program to use DebugGL4 and am not getting any error messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In LWJGL which works pretty same way, when I need to pass zero in indices slot I did it this way :
(IntBuffer)null. Just casting null to be of the buffer type.

Comment: Thank you! It worked to just pass in null without casting, too.